# C++/OOP Associations model and database

Tags: c++, database, oop, model

*Edit: I called it association because in my head it should be this, but it seems that I implement it as an aggregation... This can be also discussed...*

## Context

What you learn in IT is that when you do associations, you should use pointers.

For example: You have 2 objects: Person and Movie. One Person can do several Movie and one Movie can be done by/with several Person. You would then have:

```
class Person
{
    public:
        Person::Person();
        int id;
        vector<Movie*> movies;
};
class Movie
{
    public:
        Movie::Movie();
        int id;
};
main()
{
    Person person;
    Movie *movie = new Movie;
    person.movies.push_back(movie); // With a setter it would be better but...
}
```

or something like this (please correct me if I do something wrong =D)

## Where the troubles appear

Now you have many persons and movies and you want to save it somewhere: in a database.

1. You get your person
2. You get all the movies it is associated with in order to construct the whole object.

### But how do you get them?

- **Do you reconstruct a new pointer of Movie for each Person concerned that you associate ?**
  You lose then the association property that allow the objects to be linked but live their own life.
- **Do you load all the database in RAM and...** ok forget this
- **What is the way to do it cleverly? What is the proper way given by documentations?**

I'm interested in simplified/pseudo code as examples, dissertation... Thx a lot !

Comment: I didn't know: http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/ It can be a solution not to care about it but... Let see your answers

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, and there's a number of approaches, how to bind database tables (and represent their foreign key connections).

It's not really only how to represent/handle that kind of *Domain Model* snippet, you're presenting in your code sample here.

[@Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/) provided the **[EAA pattern catalogue](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/)** you could reasonably research, and apply appropriate patterns for these kind of *`object <-> relational mapping`* problems you address.

Comment: My question (maybe not well posed) is mostly about the pointer thing... I'll read you're link.

Comment: @ochurlaud Ohh, it goes way beyond _the pointer thing_ :-P. For domain object representation, use `std::vector<Movie>`, no need for pointers.

Comment: That what i am doing at this point, but if my movie changes somewhere i have to sync all concerned persons... it's stupid! If it's really too wide, it may be better to rely on something like odb. ??

Comment: @ochurlaud There are techniques, to bind referenced tables on the fly (e.g. [`Lazy Load`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html)), or to just use them when actually needed e.g. ([`Table Data Gateway`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html)). You really have to make up your design decisions if you need a fully synchronized _Domain Model_, or other (more lightweight patterns) will fit your actual use cases. Sorry, but as mentioned, the topic is broad.

Comment: Don't be sorry, it's still something. There are lots of concepts i didn't know, and had not heard about. Its my first huge project with databases so...i discover. Thank you.